# Laravel redirect back csrf_token mismatch exception

Tags: php, laravel-5

As following the documentation for Laravel 5.4:

I am redirect user back if validation fails like this:

```
 return redirect('login')->withErrors('Email/password combination not recognised');
```

It takes me back to login route, shows me the form and when I hit submit again it shows csrf_token mismatch. Whether I use back() or redirect() same thing happens.

```
@if(count($errors)>0)
<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
    <strong>Errors:</strong>
    @foreach($errors->all() as $error)
    <li> {{ $error }} </li>
    @endforeach
</div>
@endif

{{ Form::open(['url' => url('login') ]) }}

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="email" class="col-md-4 control-label">Email</label>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control" name="email" value="" required autofocus>

    </div>
</div>
<br>
<br>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="password" class="col-md-4 control-label">Password</label>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control" name="password" required>

    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-4">
        <div class="checkbox">
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="remember"> Remember Me
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-4">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
            Login                                </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
{{ Form::close() }}
```

Comment: Please post your code, HTML form and handling script.

Comment: Check form code. I am using Form::open()

Comment: Don't know, try put `{{csrf_field()}}` manually

Comment: @JozefCipa it worked. When I was being redirect back, I inspected source and auto generated input field for _token had no value. Adding a manual input worked. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll leave it here for those searching it later...

When you redirect back to previous form using back() or redirect(). Form::open() does generate csrf token input but gives it empty value. By adding it manually using {{csrf_field()}} it wont generate this exception.

Answer (score 1):

Make Sure the user has not been autenticate and validate the **csrf_token** after and before the redirect.

Use `<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">` in the head of your HTML.

If you are using jquery Ajax add:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});
```

To your base app layout inside a script tag.

Check out https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/csrf

Comment: Sir its not ajax

Comment: Sure. I got that. I wanted to cover all the scenarios possibles to answer your question.